# In marshmallow GPlus and Facebook login not working after creating signed apk

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-plus-signin

Google plups and facebook login not working after making signed .apk file.

Loging working properly before signing the apk.

Comment: you changed your computer before you generate signed .apk ?

Comment: no Vishal, it's working fine before i am going to make sign apk

Comment: i'm asking about your code developed and you generated an signed .apk is on same system ?

Comment: Have you generated signed apk from another system  ? or from same system in which it's working before.

Comment: Must be sure that hash key and API key must be for release apk

Comment: because sometime it was happened of change in hashkey when you change your computer

Comment: @jaydroider. i created signed apk from same system . signed .apk file working on below lollipop version.

Comment: @PrashantDate Make sure you have `api key` and `hash key` for release mode apk not debug.

Comment: @jaydroid how i can find **api key** & **hash key** for release mode

Comment: It's working fine below version lollipop.

Comment: Please check my answer on following link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46394096/7758211

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the SHA-1 you provided to the platforms. For Facebook go to [Facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android) select you app and follow the steps, in the last step you'll have to introduce the SHA-1 of your new keystore that you used for sining the app. For google go to [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com), select your project and go to configuration project. There you can add your new fingerprint SHA-1

Comment: does we get different SHA1 after signing the application ?

Comment: Yes, when you are debugging your app with Eclipse/Android Studio the application signs with the android debug keystore.

Comment: yes, but while creating keytool it asking for  debug or release keytool. at that time i selected release option

Comment: use this to know the SHA1 of your signing keystore: keytool -list -v -keystore /yourpath/keystore