# Facebook and google login is not working on beta testing APK

Tags: android, facebook-login, google-signin

The Google and Facebook logins are working fine in Android Studio Tools, but they're not working on test version or beta testing, so please give me any clue to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you upload your code??

Comment: Me too have this issue. When I tested the signed release apk its working fine. Then uploaded that apk to beta version of playstore. But still G+ login, Facebook login, Google places search and Google maps are not working in beta version.

Comment: Any fix did you guys found. i am also stuck with the same issue

Answer (score 9):

**I had fixed this issue after contacting google support.**

Below is the fix for this issue. Please follow the steps.

1. To fix google login - Whenever you will create a debug or release apk, please make sure to update **Package name** and **SHA1 fingerprint** in your API key at "https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=???".

Please note SHA1 fingerprint will differ for debug and release build, so place it accordingly in google console.

2. To fix facebook login - Whenever you will create a debug or release apk, please go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and choose your app and go to **Settings --> Basic** and add your **Key Hashes** for debug and release.

Hopefully this will fix your issue but if its not then please go to step 3.

3. Now you have to check for your app enrolled in **Google Play App Signing** or not. To check this please go to **[Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)** and choose your app that is published in beta and navigate to **Release Management --> App Signing**. There you will find the text at top **"Google Play App Signing is enabled for this app"**. If so then copy the SHA1 certificate fingerprint from "**App signing certificate**" and add this SHA1 key as mentioned in 1st step. Now test after 5 or 10 minutes, your Google login will start work in the beta app.
4. Now you have to add the **Key Hash** of SHA1 (which we got from step 3) to Facebook console as like mentioned in step 2. Don't worry how to change this SHA1 to that Key Hash format. You can easily get it, please connect your beta version app in Android Studio and try to login in Facebook from your app and check Logcat from Android Studio, there you will find that Key Hash for this SHA1. To add it please follow step 2. Now your Facebook login also will start to work.

Useful link which is related to above fix - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: This saved me! Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you, boss. Save my day.

Comment: It’s my pleasure.

Comment: i have been looking for like 2 weeks . thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

You must generate a keyhash for live sever and update to Facebook. You would have only used development keyhash.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. when I debug my code on vscode it was working fine but in internal testing stage sign in with google was not working. I changed my sha-1 fingerprints in firebase with sha-1 that is given by google play console. Here is link; https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/8739345695749690484/app/4974329906490558980/keymanagement

if you can't open the link you should follow that;
**https://play.google.com/apps/publish --> Select app --> Setup(in release part) --> app integrity**

In App signing key certificate part  with SHA-1 certificate fingerprint